# Как в контактной форме wordpress формат поля даты укоротить до отображения только лет без месяцев и дней?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form7

У меня сайт на **wordpress** с контактной формой [contact form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)
Как сделать поле даты с текстовым плейсхолдером, в котором можно выбирать только годы (постройки) ?

Первую часть вопроса решил таким образом: в момент клика на текстовое поле с плейсхолдером, тип поля меняется на дату.

В форме добавлено поле

```
[text* company-built class:wc7data placeholder "Year built"][submit class:btn "SEND"]
```

Код замены:

```
$(document).on('focus','.wc7data', function (e) {
  this.type='date';
});
$(document).on('blur','.wc7data', function (e) {
  this.type='text';
});
```

Comment: Почему для этого не использовать цифровое поле, а не поле даты?

Comment: @SeVlad нужен плейсхолдер

Comment: И что ж мешает его использовать в цифровом поле? https://contactform7.com/number-fields/